# Using LINQ To Find Total Number of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, linq, class, object

I have a class Customer that holds an array of class Order.

```
    class Customer
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public Order[] orders {get; set;}
}
```

I need to write a LINQ to find the total number of orders of all customers but I don't understand how to do it. For example I have created 8 customers and they have 3 orders each so I should print out 24.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please provide some code which you already did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use either of these.

```
// flattens order collection.
var result = custList.SelectMany(x => x.orders).Count();
```

or

```
var result = custList.Sum(x=>x.orders.Count());
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick! Thank you. I think I understand how to use LINQ on objects of object.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = custList.SelectMany(x => x.orders).Count();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So that returns for me 8 which is probably seeing an order for each customer but not counting the number of orders per customer....which should be returning 24 in my case

Comment: you should use selectMany in that case

Comment: Correct - the select is returning an `Order[]` for each customer, and then counting the number of those - which will be the same as the number of customers. You'll need to use `Sum` or `SelectMany` as proposed in the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `SelectMany()`. This method will makes one list of all orders. Then you can do count:

`var allordersNumber = customers.SelectMany(x => x.Orders).Count();`

Please read more about `SelectMany()` in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You certainly can do it as `var countOfOrders = customers.SelectMany(x => x.orders).Count();`, but you many find it more readable as this:

```
var orders =
    from c in customers
    from o in c.orders
    select o;

var countOfOrders = orders.Count();
```